# Как убрать фон у input'а?

Tags: html, css

Как убрать фон белый у этой кнопки? То что серое это и есть фон заданный ей через background-color,но фон у нее не изменился(который белый).[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не помогает,убирается только сервый фон,сейчас код дам

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/d9k6jto4/

Comment: Тогда остается сделать костылём

Answer (score 4):

Вместо background-color просто background

Answer (score 2):

```css
.dropZoneOverlay,
.FileUpload {
  width: 283px;
  height: 71px;
}

.dropZoneOverlay {
  border: dotted 1px;
  font-family: cursive;
  color: #7066fb;
  position: absolute;
  //background: red;
  top: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}

.FileUpload {
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropZoneContainer">
  <input type="file" id="drop_zone" class="FileUpload" accept=".jpg,.png,.gif" onchange="handleFileSelect(this) " />
  <div class="dropZoneOverlay">Drag and drop your image <br />or<br />Click to add</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Применить стиль к

```
input[type="button" i], input[type="submit" i], input[type="reset" i], input[type="file" i]::-webkit-file-upload-button, button
```